# Understanding the tagVARIANT struct

Tags: c++, com, variant

The COM `VARIANT` type is defined using the `tagVARIANT` structure like this:

```
typedef struct tagVARIANT {
  union {
    struct {
      VARTYPE vt;
      WORD    wReserved1;
      WORD    wReserved2;
      WORD    wReserved3;
      union {
        LONGLONG     llVal;
        LONG         lVal;
        BYTE         bVal;
        SHORT        iVal;
        FLOAT        fltVal;
        DOUBLE       dblVal;
        VARIANT_BOOL boolVal;
        VARIANT_BOOL __OBSOLETE__VARIANT_BOOL;
        SCODE        scode;
        CY           cyVal;
        DATE         date;
        BSTR         bstrVal;
        IUnknown     *punkVal;
        IDispatch    *pdispVal;
        SAFEARRAY    *parray;
        BYTE         *pbVal;
        SHORT        *piVal;
        LONG         *plVal;
        LONGLONG     *pllVal;
        FLOAT        *pfltVal;
        DOUBLE       *pdblVal;
        VARIANT_BOOL *pboolVal;
        VARIANT_BOOL *__OBSOLETE__VARIANT_PBOOL;
        SCODE        *pscode;
        CY           *pcyVal;
        DATE         *pdate;
        BSTR         *pbstrVal;
        IUnknown     **ppunkVal;
        IDispatch    **ppdispVal;
        SAFEARRAY    **pparray;
        VARIANT      *pvarVal;
        PVOID        byref;
        CHAR         cVal;
        USHORT       uiVal;
        ULONG        ulVal;
        ULONGLONG    ullVal;
        INT          intVal;
        UINT         uintVal;
        DECIMAL      *pdecVal;
        CHAR         *pcVal;
        USHORT       *puiVal;
        ULONG        *pulVal;
        ULONGLONG    *pullVal;
        INT          *pintVal;
        UINT         *puintVal;
        struct {
          PVOID       pvRecord;
          IRecordInfo *pRecInfo;
        } __VARIANT_NAME_4;
      } __VARIANT_NAME_3;
    } __VARIANT_NAME_2;
    DECIMAL decVal;
  } __VARIANT_NAME_1;
} VARIANT;
```

I'm just wondering: what do all those `__VARIANT_NAME_...` labels mean?

I'm trying to construct one of these manually in VBA, and would like to understand what all the members mean

Comment: Identifiers that contain two consecutive underscores are reserved for the implementation and are usually used for things that are private to the implementation. In other words, if it contains a double underscore you probably shouldn't be using it.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux well the [MSDN article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/windows/win32/api/oaidl/ns-oaidl-variant) where I found this has the code tagged as C++. I'm actually coming at this from a COM/VBA point of view so I don't really know what language to tag

Comment: Support for anonymous unions has been spotty for a long time, https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/g-fact-38-anonymous-union-and-structure/

Comment: @HansPassant those unions are unnamed though, not anonymous. Also contrary to what your linked page says, anonymous unions are standard in C++ (since C++11). Anonymous structs are not. Both unnamed unions and unnamed structs are standard C++.

Comment: You should post the DECIMAL question separately. It’s a really good one. I never noticed that the DECIMAL member was outside struct that had `vt`. I would really like to know too.

Comment: @EuroMicelli https://stackoverflow.com/q/59899919/6609896

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> What does __VARIANT_NAME_1 mean in a union struct?
>
> ```
> typedef struct tagVARIANT {
>   union {
>     ....
>   } __VARIANT_NAME_1;
> } VARIANT;
> ```

It is the name of a variable of that unnamed union type. In this context, the variable is a member of `tagVARIANT`.

P.S. `__VARIANT_NAME_1` and several other names in that definition are names reserved to the language implementation.

Comment: Of course! I was thrown by the fact that the union is unnamed so you don't need to explicitly qualify member calls with those labels, like `__VARIANT_NAME_1.__VARIANT_NAME_2.__VARIANT_NAME_3.boolVal`. Do you know the answer to the second question; if I use a Decimal then how does the caller know what type is in the Variant without a VARTYPE member?

Answer (score 2):

if NONAMELESSUNION is defined then __VARIANT_NAME_1-2-3-4 evaluate to n1,n2,n3,n4 respectively, otherwise they will be blank, making them nameless unions.

```c
#ifdef NONAMELESSUNION
#define __VARIANT_NAME_1 n1
#define __VARIANT_NAME_2 n2
#define __VARIANT_NAME_3 n3
#define __VARIANT_NAME_4 n4

#else

#define __tagVARIANT
#define __VARIANT_NAME_1
#define __VARIANT_NAME_2
#define __VARIANT_NAME_3
#define __VARIANT_NAME_4
#endif
```

VBA doesnt have "unions" so you need to make a structure something like this (vba does have structures if i remember right, its been a while)

```vb
Public Type MyVariant
   vt As VarType ' or Integer
   Value As String * (Longest size of a VBA (or Variant) type Possible, probably 16)
   Dec As Decimal
End Type
```

and then handle copying the data to and from `Value` using RtlMoveMemory() and using the `vt` field to determine size and type of the data in 'Value'. Im guessing Currency or Long64 will be your biggest type other than Decimal. Strings and Arrays will be pointers.