# 64 bit unsigned integer division in VBA

Tags: vba, integer, division, unsigned, unsigned-integer

I have a function that returns unsigned 64 bit integers, which VBA does not support. I have seen workarounds using `Currency` but I want to do it using `Type` instead. This is what I came up with:

```
Public Type LARGE_INTEGER
    LoPart As Long
    HiPart As Long
End Type

Private Const SCALE_UP As Double = 2^32 - 1

Public Function IntegerDivide(ByRef numerator As LARGE_INTEGER, ByRef denominator As LARGE_INTEGER) As Double
    IntegerDivide = Normalify(numerator) / Normalify(denominator)
End Function

Public Function Largify(ByVal normal As Double) As LARGE_INTEGER
    Largify.HiPart = normal / SCALE_UP
    Largify.LoPart = normal - Largify.HiPart * SCALE_UP
End Function

Public Function Normalify(ByRef large As LARGE_INTEGER) As Double
    Normalify = large.HiPart * SCALE_UP + large.LoPart
End Function
```

I have a feeling it could be buggy because of off-by-one errors or two's complement. But I don't know this stuff well enough. Is this correct?

e.g. here's an example function that returns a 64 bit unsigned integer

```
Private Declare Function QueryPerformanceCounter Lib "KERNEL32" (ByRef outTickCount As LARGE_INTEGER) As Long 'BOOL
```

Comment: Have you seen this: [64-bit Unsigned Integers in VBA](https://nolongerset.com/64-bit-unsigned-integers-in-vba/)?

Comment: @Pᴇʜ Yeah that's the inspiration, but it dosn't have division and also uses the currency trick which requires CopyMemory and I want to avoid that.

Comment: @Greedo You definitely want the decimal type as suggested in the answer below. Especially for results. The Double data type can't hold more that 15 digits (16 with the dot). For example ```CDbl("8070450532247928832") / CDbl("2483356")``` returns ```3249816189160.12``` while ```CDec("8070450532247928832") / CDec("2483356")``` returns ```3249816189160.1239741704371021```. It's unfortunate that Dec is not available on Mac but I doubt you need it as you're using Windows APIs. As you correctly pointed out, you don't need CopyMemory because you can make the API parameters as ```ByVal ... LongPtr```

Comment: @Greedo Also, it's correct to call the API using ```varptr(decimal) + 8``` even though the decimal type uses the reserved 6 bytes of the variant (byte 3 to 8).

Comment: @Greedo already deleted the incorrect comment. :). Did not realize you were the OP for that [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59899919/8488913). Worth having the link here, I guess.

Comment: Yes I only want to write the lower half because it's LSB

Answer (score 1):

You have the Decimal type readily available that can perform operations on integers up to 12 bytes.

You can't declare variables as "Decimal" but you can declare them as "Variant" and use the "Cdec" function to convert them to decimal and then all integer operations will work correctly on these BIG integers.

Comment: But how can I do `CDec(LARGE_INTEGER)` in the first place. I have an API function that returns 64 bit integers, how do I get them into a Variant/Decimal?

Comment: Well it would help if you mentioned which API function you are talking about but basically you can use CopyMemory to copy the value returned by the API function inside the decimal variant. I'll show you the code if you can say which API function we are talking about.

Comment: In the case of "QueryPerformanceCounter" you should definitely use the "Currency" type. If you want to use your LARGE_INTEGER type you may end up with negative numbers for HiPart or LoPart since the "Long" type only goes up to 2^31-1.

Comment: Yeah I realise because you always divide QueryPerformanceCounter by QueryPerformanceFrequency it doesn't actually matter that currency is the wrong scale since it cancels out. You can also use varptr(decimal) + 8 to write the unsigned int to the variable without copymemory. I want to avoid any floating point errors

Comment: You only get floating point errors with double type if your integers are 6 bytes or larger since the double type needs some bytes left over for holding the digits that follow the floating point. It's perfectly safe to use for integers smaller than 6 bytes. If you know you will need bigger integers then switch to Cdec(Variant).