# Are there any potiential issues using LSet with UDT's, especially into a smaller UDT?

Tags: vba, ms-access

In the Add function below using the LSet command with UDT's, are there potiential issues using LSet into a smaller UDT?  It appears to function correctly transferring the lower 4 bytes of the LongLong within a QWORD UDT into the ULong 4 bytes structure.  Also is it compatible with VB6?

Below is an extract of the class ULong32.cls for unsigned 32-bit values from [ULong32.cls](https://github.com/MarkJohnstoneGitHub/VBA-Library/blob/main/scr/DataTypes/ULong32.cls)

'QWordType.bas

```
#If VBA7 Then
    Public Type QWORD
        Value As LongLong
    End Type
#Else
    Public Type QWORD
        LowPart     As Long     ' the ordering is important to remain consistant with memory layout of a 64-bit integer.
        HighPart    As Long
    End Type
#End If
```

'ULongType.bas

```
Public Type ULong
    Value As Long
End Type

Public Function Add(ByRef lhs As ULong, ByRef rhs As ULong) As ULong
    Dim qwLhs As QWORD
    Dim qwRhs As QWORD
    
    LSet qwLhs = lhs
    LSet qwRhs = rhs
    
    Dim qwResult As QWORD
    qwResult.Value = qwLhs.Value + qwRhs.Value
    
    If qwResult.Value > 4294967295# Then
       Err.Raise OverflowException, "UInt32.Multiply"
    End If
    LSet Add = qwResult
End Function
```

Have tried various methods this one seems to perform the best and checking for any potiental issues overlooked using  LSet and UDT's.

Comment: `using LSet into a smaller UDT` - where is it doing that?

Comment: @GSerg the LSet Add = qwResult .   Add is ULong of 4 bytes the qwResult is 8 bytes.  Hard to find much on LSet and this particular use possible questionable but seems to work fine. x fingers no  memory leaks etc.

Comment: It certainly [does the right thing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/visualstudio/visual-basic-6/aa266163(v=vs.60)) for strings; I would say it's safe to assume it does the same with binary.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not a problem.

To be certain, you can just check this:

```vb
Type OneLong
    Long1 As Long
End Type

Type TwoLong
    Long1 As Long
    Long2 As Long
End Type

Type OneLongSurroundedByLong
    LongBefore As Long
    SurroundedLong As OneLong
    LongAfter As Long
End Type

Public Sub Check()
    Dim source As TwoLong
    Dim test As OneLongSurroundedByLong
    
    source.Long1 = &HFFFF ' Init bytes as all 1
    source.Long2 = &HFFFF

    'Do the copy
    LSet test.SurroundedLong = source
    ' Verify no buffer overflow occurred, the value got set and the variables are ordered as expected
    Debug.Print test.LongBefore; test.LongAfter; test.SurroundedLong.Long1; VarPtr(test.LongBefore); VarPtr(test.SurroundedLong); VarPtr(test.LongAfter)
End Sub
```

Run this code, and you'll see that the destination correctly got written to, without overflowing in the adjacent memory.

Comment: Thanks will check it out later.  Giving me  the assurance to update the maths functions in the unsigned 32-bit type.  Pity I'm having issues using LSet with a variant in a UDT was pushing hope for it to work with the Decimal type when next work on a UInt64.

Comment: Thanks confirmed no isssue with overflowing into adjacent memory.  I checked it out with a memory dump class I did and looks good. :D

Comment: Regarding variants in UDTs (and similarly variable-length strings and objects: using these "reference types" with LSet is hard and requires knowledge of how they work in memory. There are [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/oaidl/ns-oaidl-variant), but these tend to not be trivial to implement. Working with decimals is especially hard if you want to do anything not built into COM.

Comment: Working the decimal type isn't hard once understand it's structure within a variant I posted on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59899919/how-does-the-caller-know-when-theres-a-decimal-inside-a-variant/75511339#75511339  Using the Decimal type for a "quick" and  "easy" solution handing casting unsigned values.  Performance  wise well once you build the structure and Copy memory it takes a noticeable hit. The  LSet is handy casting to larger numeric types avoiding VBA doing negative conversions.  I don't will work on the Decimal type, first attempt wouldn't  let me compile it.